# What is the use of Percent-S (%s) at the end of strings? (Not string formatting)

Tags: string-formatting, configuration-files

I'm trying to configure the browser for Jupyter Notebook, and in the .jupyter config file, I am confused by this line.

**What is the point of %s at the end of the string?**

```
c.NotebookApp.browser = u'open -a chrome.exe %s'
```

When I search for %s in strings on the internet, I get the pages related to string formatting (where the string is followed by an additional % variable, to substitute the variable into the string). **This is totally unrelated isn't it?**

Comment: I know nothing about Jupyter, but... my guess here is that you are setting the `c.NotebookApp.browser` so that it can open an HTML link (local or remote) that would reside in the `%s` parameter much like `printf`.

Comment: Hi JNevill, i think I understand. We have a variable called s, with the html link that I would open! Thanks

Comment: Oh correcting myself, s is not the variable name, but just the placeholder type (string). The variable name should come later, but hasn't been shown in the config file?

Comment: Under the hood it's probably doing something like `printf c.NotebookApp.browser, someURLVariable` which may rectify to: `printf "open -a chrome.exe %s", "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52954662"` which generates the string `open -a chrome https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52954662` which is then eval'd or shot to a shell or something (totally guessing at the stack here).

Comment: i updated my answer to explain why string formatting is applied to the config file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The string is likely passed to `sprintf()`, which inserts a string parameter in place of `%s`. See `man printf`.

In this case, the URL in inserted as a parameter for the open command.

The author of the config file format decided to use string formatting here, so you can insert the URL parameter anywhere in the string, and not only at the end of it, i.e.:

```
c.NotebookApp.browser = u'/usr/bin/my_browser -new -url %s -some -more -parameters'
```

Then at runtime of the application, the URL parameter is injected with string formatting:

```
shellCmd = config.NotebookApp.browser % targetUrl
```

It is important. Don't delete it.

Comment: But we have not defined which variable would be subbed in. (why doesn't the line continue by saying "% html_link"

Comment: @Adrian because you are looking at a config file that is only defining constants. At runtime, the application uses this string to start a browser and "feed" it with the URL to open as a parameter. The configured constant `c.NotebookApp.browser` is used with string formatting at runtime. i.e. `cmd = c.NotebookApp.browser % url`

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense!